# Why does my walk cycle look so weird?

Tags: animation, graph-editor, timeline

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84psGO2X0bs

I need to get some feedback on this walk cycle I'm using in a couple of days. I feel like the timing of the legs is the reason that it's looking wonky because in the upper body view it looks fine.

Thanks for reading, you guys that are helping me out are legends.

Comment: he looks like he's limping, but you should share your armature, it would help

Comment: Why would it help if he shared his armature, @moonboots ?

Comment: There's a very good and highly detailed YT series on creating a realistic walk cycle [here](https://youtu.be/oZ14vidzSs4). I've followed it using a low poly model and the result looked really authentic.

Comment: @ Alexandre Marcati because we could see his animation in detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few reasons...

The main reason is because the walk is asymetrical and each foot's cycle is out of phase with the other. When one foot is planted on the ground and the body is aligned over the foot, the other foot should be in the middle of the trajectory towards the front. In your cycle, it looks like this:
[image]

Notice how his left foot is already out to the front. That's imbalanced.

Also the right foot stays on the ground for slightly longer than the left foot. That's also weird and makes it look like he has a limp.

Another thing that is weird is that he walks with his legs a little bended and the leg only extends when the foot is behind. That's not how a person walks. The leg is extended when it's aligned with the body (pushing the body up) and while it 'pushes' the ground backwards. When the foot is behind, the knee bends a little and the heel gets off from the ground (but the end of the foot and toes are still on the ground).

See this cycle from "The Animator's Survival Kit":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using inverse kinematics, it makes animating a lot easier, but if not, then rotate the bone that controls the foot to look how it looks in the walk cycle. Just keep on tweaking until it looks how you want it, by rotating, and moving. :3